# Where Does The Meat Come From

Tags: pokemon

In the Pokemon series where Ash travels with Iris and Cilan mainly, the gang does eat food that contains meat. This includes sandwiches, steak, and other non-vegan recipes. There aren't any real meat sources other than Pokemon.

Where did the meat come from? Did people actually hunt Pokemon for meat?

Comment: I recall one occasion (perhaps one of the Pichu Bros films?) where Meowth mentioned having a turkey sandwich.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are real animals in the Pokémon universe, you just don't see them that often because they aren't any use in fighting, and probably don't live in the same habitats as Pokémon as they'd have no chance to defend themselves against them, and as the main characters are all trainers, those are the sort of areas that the show is most commonly set.

There's a very extensive list of animals in the Pokémon universe on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world#In_the_anime) which includes direct sightings of worms, lobsters, fish, crabs, starfish, seagulls, swordfish and shrimp. Furthermore, there is also evidence of people keeping pets, such as tins of cat food, as well as characters mentioning concepts which indicate the existence of animals, such as 'lion tamers' and 'chicken feed', as well as a scene where Ash dresses up as a cow.